# add html to invoice pdf Magento

Tags: php, magento, pdf, invoice

I am trying to add a disclaimer text to my Invoice PDF.
Currently the text is hard coded in `Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php`.

```
public function getDesclaimer($page)
{
    $page->drawLine(25, $this->y, 570, $this->y); 
    $this->y -= 25;
    $this->_setFontRegular($page, 12);
    $page->drawText(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Declaration'), 35, $this->y-20, 'UTF-8');
    $this->_setFontRegular($page, 8);
    $page->drawText(Mage::helper('sales')->__('The goods sold are intended for end user consumption and not for resale.'), 35, $this->y-50, 'UTF-8');
    $page->drawText(Mage::helper('sales')->__('The goods sold are intended for end user consumption and not for resale.'), 35, $this->y-60, 'UTF-8');
    $page->drawText(Mage::helper('sales')->__('of goods specified in this tax invoice is made by me/us and that the transaction of sale covered by this tax invoice has been effected by me/us'), 35, $this->y-70, 'UTF-8');
    $page->drawText(Mage::helper('sales')->__('and it shall be accounted for in the turnover of sales while filling of return and the due tax,if any payable on the sale has been paid or shall be paid.'), 35, $this->y-80, 'UTF-8');
    $page->drawText(Mage::helper('sales')->__('This is a computer generated invoice.'), 35, $this->y-100, 'UTF-8');
}
```

This works. No I added a configuration to the magento settings and call it under the same function.

This displays the proper text but HTML are not working.

When I searched got that zend pdf does not allow html in pdf. We need to use TCPDF. I tried that as well but it is giving a whole new page without other data.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't edit the core file. You have to **create a module** for **overwrite** the invoice pdf function.

Using this url you can overwrite invoice pdf function.

http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-custom-attribute-to-magentos-pdf-invoice/

Try the above URL and customize as your requirement.